# MongoDB Java object variables must be public to be deserialized?

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize MongoDB documents into "User" objects. I was having issues where it told me I needed a "public constructor" and it took me a while to find out I had to provide a empty constructor for the User class. It was then setting all the variables to null, untill I made them all public. The below code works, but is there a way I can avoid my variables needing to be public? I would prefer for them to be private, tho this breaks MongoDB deserialization with PojoCodec

User Document

```
_id:61aad45834362a40eebf73ed
email:"myemail@gmail.com"
name:"MyName"
password:"lol"
points:0
avatar:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/34AD2.jpg"
group:"2fakwn"
```

User.java class

```
public class User {
 
// How can i make these private??
public String email;
public String name;
public String password;
public int points;
public String avatar;
public String group;

public User() {
    
}

public User(String email, String name, String password, String avatar) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    points = 0;
    this.avatar= avatar;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void addPoints(int p) {
    points += p;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return group;
}
```

Search query

```
    // Register codecs     
    CodecRegistry defaultCodecRegistry = MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
    CodecRegistry fromProvider = CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(defaultCodecRegistry, fromProvider);
    
    // Setup MongoDB client with URI and connect to main database.
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(System.getenv("DATABASE"));
    MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(connectionString).codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).build();
    
    // Initialize collections and indexes if they don't exist.
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("ChoreSplitter").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
    users = database.getCollection("users");
    users.createIndex(Filters.eq("group", 1)); 

    Bson match = Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("group", code));
    Bson sort = Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("points"));
    List<User> users.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, sort), User.class).into(new ArrayList<User>());
    //I then print out this info
```

Comment: The last line looks syntactically incorrect: `List<User> users.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, sort), User.class).into(new ArrayList<User>());`, does it compile? Also, please show us the type of `users`.

Comment: Yes it compiles, the code runs perfectly for me. I just am only able to get it to run without errors when the variables of User.java are public. `users` is a collection from mongodb, ill update the example above rn